# Intent to play sound from raw folder

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to use the systems audio/video player to play a sound from my raw folder but I keep on getting the same "No activity found to handle Intent" message (exception) when firing the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackagename/" + R.raw.audiofile), "audio/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: R.raw.audiofile is an integer. not a file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following (Where soundfile is the name of the file in the raw folder without extension. Use only lowercase characters, please):

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer(this,R.raw.soundfile);

player.prepare();
player.start();
```

.
.
.

```
player.stop();
player.reset();
player.release();
player = null;
```

Found [here](http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/playing-audio-in-android).

Answer (score 1):

The way the intent system works is that your app is basically saying, "Hey Android, I have this url and I want to *view* it.  Is there an app on the phone that will do that?"

For http urls, you've got your browser installed on the phone, for google play urls it'll show you the google play store as an option, etc etc.  If you don't have an app on your phone that will handle audio resources (which there isn't one installed by default whatever that means for android).

Just like Dirk said, you have to use the MediaPlayer to play your resources.  The MediaPlayer page is pretty sweet: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html